# Do blocks in Haskell not behaving as expected

Tags: haskell, monads

```
filterA = [3]
filterB = [2]
output = []

funA n =
if not (elem (n) filterA)
    then do  
        filterA ++ [(3 * n + 2) ] 
        filterB ++ [(3 * n + 2) ]
        output ++ [(3 * n + 2)]
        else output
```

It seems some imperative habits must be kicking in...

The point of this code is to add a value to `filterA`, `filterB` and `output`, so long as `n` is not part of the corresponding filter list (for this function it's `filterA`). Accepted inputs are added to both filters, even though the B function (which would look similar) is not shown here.

I am clearly misunderstanding the way `do` works, as a result that runs through the `do` block in this code gives back something like this:

`*Main> funA 4
 [14,14,14,14]`

I'm not understanding how adding to separate lists in a `do` block is getting all mixed up. How do I perform multiple actions under the same function without them interfering with each other?

To add to that, if I remove one of the `filterA ++ [(3 ...` lines the result becomes `[14,14]` and removing both gives the desired result `[14]`, minus of course concatenating values to `filterA` or `filterB`. But something about having both of them produces four replicates.

TL:DR How do I execute multiple separate actions inside of a `do` block? Is it possible to understand without going in depth into monads? Am a missing a more simple solution?

Comment: what do you think `filterA ++ [(3 * n + 2)]` is doing?

Comment: I was thinking that it 'added' to filterA. But now I believe it is creating a new list out of the two values on either side of ++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append list is not an action. `filterA ++ [3 * n + 2]` is not an action but an expression. It evaluates to list.

You may want to use an IO monad. But the return type of the function you defined is List and not IO. In your definition, do block expresses a list monad and not an IO monad.

And in Haskell, the value once defined is not to be changed.

You may want to do following.

```
funA n = if not (elem n filterA)
        then let
                filterA' = filterA ++ [3 * n + 2]
                filterB' = filterB ++ [3 * n + 2]
                output' = output ++ [3 * n + 2] in
                (filterA', filterB', output')
        else (filterA, filterB, output)
```